# Parquet Footer Specification

Tags: footer, parquet

Is there a detailed Parquet Footer Specification?
I am seeing the Parquet Footer get very large as I am converting data programmatically to Parquet.  I realize it has block offsets and min/max values for the blocks but there seems like a lot more info going in there.
Knowing more of the footer design may allow me to make trade-offs in block size, block count and footer size.
Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 2):

The parquet file format is specified using [thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) in the [parquet-format github repository](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/apache-parquet-format-2.8.0/src/main/thrift/parquet.thrift). The [metadata section of the readme](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format#metadata) also shows a graphical overview of the structure.

There shouldn't be any large amount of data in this structure, but the footer can also contain additional arbitrary `key_value_metadata` pairs. This is often used to store an original schema, for example avro, in text format and could maybe add a few kilobytes.